# Uploading image to WCF service gets image size reduced and image is not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, wcf, file-upload

I am trying to upload images and other files using WCF service and images and other types of files are getting uploaded successfully. But what issue I am facing is that when I upload image of few KB's it gets uploaded and I am able to open it up nicely. But when the image size is big like I tried to upload image of 800 KB only 10KB gets uploaded and also it does not open up or it is corrupt.

My web.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"    />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service
          name="ImageUploadingService.Service1"
          behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ImageUploadingService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000000"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

My Service contract is like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PostImage?fileName={fileName}&Ext={Ext}&Path={Path}", Method = "POST")]
    string PostImage(Stream sm,string fileName,string Ext,string Path);
}
```

My service class is like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string PostImage(Stream stream, string fileName, string Ext, string Path)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
        FileStream f = new FileStream(Path+fileName   , FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();
        return "Recieved the image on server";
    }
}
```

My code to upload is like this:

```
protected void btnUploadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PostData();
}
public void PostData()
{   
    string FileName="";
    string ext="";
    try
    {
        byte[] fileToSend = null; 

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            Stream stream = FileUpload1.FileContent;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileToSend = new byte[stream.Length];
            int count = 0;
            while (count < stream.Length)
            {
                fileToSend[count++] = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
            }
        }

        //Here provide your service location url in below line. You need to host your service on server(IIS or which one you prefer)
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49287/Service1.svc/PostImage?fileName="+FileName+"&Ext="+ ext +"&Path=C:\\Users\\mubashir.gul\\Documents\\mydocs\\");//PostImage?fileName={fileName}&Ext={Ext}&Path={Path}

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
        req.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any type of suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You service code contains these lines:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
```

Which are ~10 Kb you're talking about.

Try to change service method to following:

```
    FileStream f = new FileStream(Path+fileName   , FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    stream.CopyTo(f);
    f.Close();
    stream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Igor..working smoothly....but page crashes when I select more than 20mb file ...any suggestions please.

Comment: I bet you may be hitting some timeout. As far as I understand you get some exception (you have try/catch around your code). Could you please post which exception you get - then I'll be able to tell better how to deal with it.